# Paste multiple string variables across multiple cells in Excel via VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to copy multiple variables in Excel to the clipboard. My aim is that when these are pasted, each variable is pasted into its own cell.

```
Public height As Integer
Public width As Integer
Public top As Integer

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Copy the dimensions to the clipboard
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Sub CopyDimensions()

    Dim txt As String

    txt = height & "|" & width & "|" & top

    ' Place text into the Clipboard
    ' From http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2015/1/13/how-to-use-vba-code-to-copy-text-to-the-clipboard
    ClipBoard_SetData txt

End Sub
```

I've just used the pipe to differentiate between each variable.

Now, when I paste the clipboard contents, it only appears in one single cell. Is there a way that every integer, seperated by a pipe, goes into its own cell?

The `ClipBoard_SetData` function can be found [here](http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2015/1/13/how-to-use-vba-code-to-copy-text-to-the-clipboard). It's a fix from Microsoft.

Comment: What's the `ClipBoard_SetData` sub?

Comment: Added to the question body. The function is a messy one!

Comment: Why use the clipboard in the first place?  Once you have the values, why not just set the cells directly?

Comment: Because the user may not wish to copy them, just view them.

Comment: and can't you use a global string variable (`Public str as String`) for that purpose ?

Comment: @PatrickLepelletier - no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was resolved by using tabs instead of pipes:

`txt = height & vbTab & width & vbTab & top`